# Efficiency of method of counting negative numbers in an matrix

Tags: performance, matrix, binary-search

I was working on a LeetCode challenge. You are asked to count the negative numbers in an array where each row is sorted in descending order from left to right and each column is sorted in descending order from top to bottom. There are other questions here related to that very challenge, but they do not answer my question.

I have solved it but my time results are a little puzzling. I should point out that the question is specifically part of a binary search study plan.

My approach was to first compare the dimensions then choose between one of two options, the options are identical except in one rows are switched for columns in the following description.

Assume I did a binary search along the bottom row to find the index j of the first negative number in the row. Now I know that all columns left of the index contain no negative numbers so I can discard them. For each of the remaining columns there is at least one negative number so I binary search each to find the index i of the first negative number. Once I found the index I know everything below it is also negative, so I subtract the index from the size of the column, then add this to the running count of negative numbers.

To decide if I do the first binary search on the last row to discard columns or do the first search on the last column to discard rows I used the heuristic of comparing m to n and chose the option that would on average minimize the number of binary searches I had to do in the second phase. Then return the running count.

My solution works but had absolutely abysmal time performance compared to all other solutions by other users. The highest performance solutions were just a straight forward pair of nested for loops counting item by item. So just for the sake of trying to achieve a decent time there I threw in a small matrix optimization (optimization for those test cases I don't think it is in general an optimization), if m*n is less than 5000, go row by row, item by item until the first negative is found, add the remaining number in one step and move on to the next row. That got me vastly improved performance.

My question is this, was my first implementation somehow flawed? Worst case time complexity for it is O(max( m*log(n), n*log(m) )). Are brute force results beating me just because the matrix sizes in the test cases must be very small? I have to believe if I were given a 100,000x100,000 matrix then it would be impossible for brute force to outperform let alone outperform by such a huge margin.

Have I incorrectly calculated the time complexity of my algorithm? Could anyone tell me what the average case time complexity of it is?

Thanks

EDIT:

Initially I implemented in C#, so out of interest I implemented the exact same solution in C++, a line for line exact duplicate. The only difference is in the C# version the matrix is passed as an int[][] and in C++ as a vector<vector>.

When I run it in C++ my time is very competitive, beating 96.68% of all other submissions. That confuses me even more. I would have assumed the C++ submissions would have been harder to beat for the simple fact that in general when comparing a C# dev to a C++ dev it is my experience that the C++ devs have a deeper knowledge of optimization techniques from general to micro optimizations and esoteric data structures.

Comment: This can be done `O(N)`.  In the first row, find the last non-negative.  Now you know that the last non-negative in the next row is either the same or smaller index.  Just keep scooting down row my row, moving your "pointer" to the left to track the boundary.

Comment: @TimRoberts The binary search still is not a bad idea when one of the dimensions is much larger than the other. E.g with `m << n` you can achieve `O(m + log n)`

Comment: "*I binary search each to find the index i of the first negative number.*" - make sure to use [exponential binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) or [interpolation binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) and to start from the index you found in the previous array, instead of starting from the beginning. Basically, this becomes *fractional cascading*.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the quick reply! Your suggestion seems so obvious, once you pointed it out, thanks you for that. Since the matrix is not guaranteed to contain a negative does it still make sense to do the first binary search on the last column to find the first row that does contain one, if any row does at all?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks to you too for the quick reply. Coincidentally enough I was reading The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena today and specifically the two variants of binary search you mention. Never thought to use them.

Comment: @Bergi Are you familiar with that text? Out of all the algorithm texts I have looked through his is easily the best. I know there is another one that is incredibly well regarded, the name and author escape me right now, but I have not had a chance to read it.

Comment: One walks the zero line border, roughly reminiscent to a circles arc. You can do a binary search of 0 in the range the prior position +/- 1 till end. What is to consider is the repetition of 0s / -1s. And the storage. If every row is implemented as consecutive vector, always starting with a loop on rows can be faster. _However:_ is binary search that much faster than a simple loop?

Comment: @JoopEggen It was part of a coding challenge question where you are supposed to use binary search, so I did. On a relatively small matrix I'm sure a simple loop is faster. I made the apparently incorrect assumption that because it was specifically worded to be a binary search problem that the test case matrices would have been constructed sufficiently large that item by item counting could not possible outperform... I was wrong. I ran tests on matrices with random dimensions between 10^5*10^5 and 10^6*10^6 and binary search always out performs. Very small, say 25*25 brute force wins.

Comment: Interesting. Vertical versus horizontal start however could have an effect when the matrix is sufficiently squarish.